# Java TicTacToe - comparing lots of values

Tags: java, while-loop

I am writing this TicTacToe game. We all know how TicTacToe works, either somebody wins or nobody wins and the board gets full.

board.playable() checks to see if somebody has won the game or if the board is full. This code runs fine but I'm just wondering if there is a tidier way to write my while loop. It just seems a bit redundant to have the same condition twice. But I need to run the board.playable() check before the computer makes his move.

```
public void runGame()
{
    while(board.playable()==true)
    {
        // Outputs a visual representation to console window
        this.displayBoard();
        // Asks player to enter a valid number
        this.playerMove();

        // Check if it still playable for the next
        if(board.playable() == true)
        {
            computerMove()
        }
    }

    this.displayBoard();

    // Outputs the final status of the game and the winner if any
    if(board.wonBoard()==true) {
        System.out.println(board.whoWon() + " has won the game");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The board is full. Nobody has won the game");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `== true` in your if and while conditions? Isn't that a bit redundant?

Comment: This question should probably be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ not SO.

Comment: @ Hovercraft: I know, that is the question I am asking. Before the player makes a move I run a check to see if it's possible to make a move. Then before the computer makes a move I run the same check.

Comment: @jimbo123: no that is not the question you're asking. It's a little bit of ugliness in your code is all.

Comment: I'd be tempted to make things more symmetrical: i.e. have two turns in each loop, called Turn1, Turn2. The turns themselves invoke either a computer or user. That way you can model two players, one player and one computer, or computer plays itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't seem to have a "turn" state. If it had such an entity, then it could play  a turn and check for winner after each turn.  Also, get rid of `== true` in all of your code.

```
while (gameNotOver) {
  // assuming an enum called Turn
  if (turn == Turn.PLAYER) {
    doPlayersTurn();
  } else {
    doComputerTurn();
  } 
  checkForWin();
  turn = turn.nextTurn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(board.playable())
    {
        // Outputs a visual representation to console window
        this.displayBoard();
        // Asks player to enter a valid number
        this.playerMove();

        // Check if it still playable for the next
        if(board.playable())
        {
            computerMove();
        }
    }
```

remove ==true

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flag to know whose move is : Like this

```
boolean playerTurn = Boolean.TRUE;
    while(board.playable()==true)
    {
        // Outputs a visual representation to console window
        this.displayBoard();
        // Asks player to enter a valid number
        if(playerTurn){
            this.playerMove();
            playerTurn=Boolean.FALSE;
        }
        else{
            computerMove();
            playerTurn = Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    }
```